# Single remote user cannot login

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I have a single user in my domain that cannot login remotely through our internet portal. All other users can log in almost within a second of trying to connect. This single user tries to login and receives a timeout error. After looking through the settings, everything as far as I can tell is turned on. The timeout happens at about a minute of trying to connect which shouldn't even occur.

I am using activity directory on Server 2008 R2. Why would a single user be singled out from remoting in through our portal if everyone else still can?

Cheers.

Comment: Is this over the Internet or within the local network? Outbound firewall can block this, as can routing problems between you and said client if over the Internet.

Comment: This is over the internet, so it could be that the user's outbound firewall is blocking this. I will ask if anything has changed on her end and see if she can confirm this. Thanks.

Comment: I asked about the abound firewall, she said nothing has changed... it used to work perfect but then just stopped.

Comment: I would work from her machine forward.  Add the exception to (or temporarily turn off) the firewall on the client and see.